# Image flow plugin crashes on ie7 when upgrated to jquery1.5.1 from jquery1.3

Tags: jquery

I am using the following plugin

http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/

and made some custom changes

It is working fine in all browsers with jquery.1.3

Recently I upgraged the jquery to jquery1.5.1

now the same image flow plugin works fine in all browsers except ie7

I can debug , but the problem is the moment i click on the drag right or left arrow , it completly crashes the browser

may i know how can i debug this kind of issue to find the root problem..

How can i know the error as the browser is completly getting closed

I reverted to jquery1.3 and it works fine

any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Have you tried all the jQuery versions from 1.3 through 1.6? Finding the first version that causes your problem might help you figure out how to fix it.

Comment: + to Mu... after you nail this down you can look at the specific API changes and delve deeper into the issue. Also have you tried a version of the plugin without your custom changes? If that works then you know it was something you did. If not then the entire plugin may need to madified to work with 1.5. 1.3 to 1.5 is a pretty significant leap.

Comment: @Thanks for the inputs , i will go in this direction for debugging...anyway to find the error before the browser gets closed.

Comment: if you use mozilla you can use firebug. and if use chrome you can use developer tools

Comment: try `http://www.phpied.com/firebug-console-for-ie/`

Comment: @nunu all other browsers are fine , I have this problem only in IE7 , otherwise i am good with debugging firefox and chrome.

Comment: another browsers work fine? no error?

Comment: could you post the pic.?

Comment: @nunu , no error they are absolutely fine , i did a jquery upgrade from 1.3.2 to 1.5.1 and started having this problem , i started comparing version by version and found jquery 1.4.3 is the one which is crashing this page, but i compared the files and they are huge changes...not getting any clue how to debug more.

Comment: haven't you try to install the latest jquery instead of upgrade?

Comment: @nunu , its simply closing the browser, i cannot take a screenshot also

Comment: @nunu didn't get you , install?? means , its just a download and include right..

Comment: @kobe: sorry, i means download.

Comment: what plugin you are using exactly??? 
1.the ie is crashing since that plugin you are using has some properties or methods not supported by ie or it requires some jquery elements which it is not getting which would have given error across all the browsers i suspect my first reason is your problem..can you let me know which plugin you are using??

Comment: what plugin you are using exactly??? 1.the ie is crashing since that plugin you are using has some properties or methods not supported by ie like filereader or 2.it requires some jquery library which it is not getting, which would have given error across all the browsers i suspect my first reason is your problem.. can you let me know which plugin you are using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem , its throwing error at the following location

**removeAttr** is throwing error , if i comment that it works

```
  $('#myImgagesDiv img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('myCustomattr')) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('myCustomattr'));
        $(this).removeAttr('myCustomattr'); // code creating problem
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually using IE7 instead of IE8 in compatibility mode, you need IE Developer Toolbar. IE8 has Developer Tools built in. EIther way, it's not as user friendly as firebug, but it will provide lots of info on what's causing your browser to crash.

Comment: its simply crashing the browser , i have developer toolbar , its not showing anything..

Comment: too bad. When something like this happens, I try things like validate the HTML, and run the javascript through jslint. HTML validator will tell you if your doctypes messed up, for example.

Answer (score 2):

could always stick alerts at every line of code to narrow down the crash location.